# Fish Shell: How can I customize the colors for the autocomplete feature?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fish, oh-my-fish

I started using Fish (and oh-my-fish) a couple of weeks ago and one of the things that I find somewhat visually hard is the default **background color of the autocomplete options** (see the ***purple background*** in the image). I tried looking in the Fish page, but couldn't find anything related to that. I'd like to know how that background color can be changed.
In case you're wondering, I'm using **LXTerminal** in LUbuntu (a Ubuntu distro with LXDE).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding to top voted answer. The command `fish_config colors` has been removed and you should instead use the following:

```
$ fish_config browse
```

Answer (score 53):

it's more convenient to setup all color configuration via fish web UI, which can be done from cli:

`fish_config colors`, which launches the config server of fish, and there are already tons of predefined color suggestion

For more info, check out [The Fish Shell](https://mvolkmann.github.io/fish-article/#ConfigurationViaWebUi)

Comment: This is just so much easier than all other methods.

Comment: This is a super easy solution and allows for many other customizations

Answer (score 24):

I found it, after checking these [docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables-color), and doing some trial and error with different environment variables that might be responsible for that feature.
The environment variable is `fish_color_search_match`

and the solution is changing the variable like:

```
$ set fish_color_search_match --background='333'
```

Where `'333'` is the color code. It is also possible to use predefined colors like `cyan`, `green`, `blue`, etc. that are available.

Also, I'm aware that maybe this belongs better in Unix&Linux StackExchange (which might have been the reason for the downvote?)

**Edit: Take into account that colors will not look correctly if your terminal is not using 256 colors.**

Comment: If somebody needs to customize the prefix as well the variable is `fish_pager_color_prefix`

Comment: Save to `~/.config/fish/config.fish` to see the changes tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The following also do the trick

```
$ fish_config
```

Reference: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_config.html